# Deriving via DeriveAnyClass not behaving the same as an emply instance declaration

Tags: haskell

I have the following code

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds, DefaultSignatures, FlexibleContexts, DeriveAnyClass, DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, UndecidableInstances #-}
module DeriveTest where

import GHC.Generics

class GenericClass a m where
instance GenericClass f m => GenericClass (M1 i c f) m
instance Condition a m => GenericClass (K1 i a) m

class Condition (a :: k) (m :: * -> *) where
instance (Condition a m, Condition b m) => Condition (a b) m
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Condition (a :: k) m

class Class (e :: (* -> *) -> *) where
    classF :: e m -> ()
    default classF :: GenericClass (Rep (e m)) m => e m -> ()
    classF = undefined
```

It defines the class `Class` of types that have a higher-kinded type as a parameter. It also defines a generic way to derive an instance of that class. Now if I declare a new datatype like this, and try to derive an instance of `Class`

```
data T a m = T
    { field :: a }
    deriving (Generic, Class)
```

I get the following error:

```
    * Overlapping instances for Condition a m
        arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
      Matching instances:
        instance [overlappable] forall k (a :: k) (m :: * -> *).
                                Condition a m
        instance forall k1 k2 (a :: k1 -> k2) (m :: * -> *) (b :: k1).
                 (Condition a m, Condition b m) =>
                 Condition (a b) m
      (The choice depends on the instantiation of `a, m'
       To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
       when compiling the other instance declarations)
    * When deriving the instance for (Class (T a))
   |
22 |     deriving (Generic, Class)
   |                        ^^^^^
```

The error sort of makes sense because I guess. The instance really does depend on the instantiation of `a`. However, if I just write an empty instance like this:

```
data T a m = T
    { field :: a }
    deriving (Generic)
instance Class (T a) -- works
```

It works. Why? And how can I make it behave the same with the deriving statement?

This is using GHC 8.2.2

Comment: @dfeuer Ok, did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `DeriveAnyClass` is to blame. I believe the real culprit is that GHC's unpredictable behavior surrounding overlapping instances. To see what I mean, let's factor out the default implementation of `classF` into its own function:

```
class Class (e :: (* -> *) -> *) where
    classF :: e m -> ()
    default classF :: GenericClass (Rep (e m)) m => e m -> ()
    classF = classFDefault

classFDefault :: forall (e :: (* -> *) -> *) (m :: * -> *).
                 GenericClass (Rep (e m)) m => e m -> ()
classFDefault = undefined
```

Now, given your definition of `T`:

```
data T a m = T
    { field :: a }
    deriving (Generic)
```

Observe that this typechecks:

```
instance Class (T a) where
  classF = classFDefault
```

But this doesn't!

```
classFT :: forall a (m :: * -> *).
           T a m -> ()
classFT = classFDefault
```

The latter fails with the same error as you would get had you attempted to derive `Class` with a `deriving` clause. Unfortunately, I have no idea why GHC accepts the former but rejects the latter, so I can only surmise that GHC is rather picky about how overlapping instances are used when typechecking, and GHC happens to get into a bad mood when it tries to solve a `Condition a m` constraint in a certain way.

It may be worth filing a bug on the [GHC issue tracker](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/newticket) about this.

Comment: It's pretty weird that dropping the `m` argument from the `Condition` class (since it isn't used at all) allows the instance for be derived. I'll open an issue, thanks.